# How do I have more than one workspace with Mercurial (hg)?

Tags: mercurial, workspace

I am just trying to my head round Mercurial, so this may be a daft question..

Open I wish to have more than one version of a program compiled on my machine, for example, I may need to single step both the “working versions” and the “bracken” version in a debugger until I find way the behave differently.

I also like to checkout to a clean workspace after I have done a check, so I can check (by doing a build) that I have not forgot to add a file.

This is easy to do in most source code control system, but Mercurial does not seem to support this. What am I missing?

Comment: it certainly is possible, out of intrest what made you think it wasn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial supports this model better than most Version Control Systems.

The trick is that you can have multiple repositories of the same code on your machine. Each repository supports one working directory, where you will keep your code.

You can move changes between the repositories, or from these to repositories on other machines, such as a central repo.

A Mercurial user might read your statement "I also like to checkout to a clean workspace after I have done a check...." as "I would like to clone a new copy of the repository after I have committed my checked code." And this is easily done.

Comment: Diskspace is getting cheaper, however as we use a SSD, space for lots of copies of a repository may still be an issue.  (+1 for explaining this well)

Comment: @IanRingrose Actually space won’t be an issue, because if you clone from one repository to another, Mercurial will hardlink the files. Because of this additional copies of a repository consumes very little additional disk space. In Lazy Badger’s example, use `hg clone dir1 dir2` for the second clone to get this behaviour. There is also a relink extension to create / update these hard links later on.

Comment: Btw, [in my experience](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/555) often the repository usually accounts for around 50% of the total size of the checkout (the other half being used by the working copy). So even if Mercurial wouldn’t create these hard links, if you have room for many working copies their repositories wouldn’t increase disk size requirements by an order of magnitude. For comparison, those .svn directories SVN creates also account for like 1/3rd of the size (237MB out of 747MB on a repository here).

Comment: @LaurensHolst, Does Mercurial do this on Windows 7 with NTFS file system, if so, it is the detail I have been missing.

Comment: @Ian Ringrose - It certainly does. This has been an area of change in the last couple of years, but current stable versions of Hg use NTFS hardlinks if available. I just verified that my TortoiseHg 2.1.2 (Hg 1.9.1 ...) does this by default.

Answer (score 1):

- hg clone URL dir1
- hg clone URL dir2

...
hack-debug-fix]
...

- hg commit
- hg push
- cd ...
- del dir*

Answer (score 1):

Anther option is the [Share Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShareExtension), distributed with **Mercurial 1.3** or later.

[See Does mercurial (hg) have functionality similar to git’s worktree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092794/does-mercurial-hg-have-functionality-similar-to-git-s-worktree)