# Does mercurial (hg) have functionality similar to git’s worktree?

Tags: mercurial

The new [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command in git allows you to have multiple working trees attached to the same repository.   Hence allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time.

This saves you from needing multiple local repositories that you have to `push` or `pull` between.

Does mercurial (hg) support something similar yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Share Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShareExtension), distributed with **Mercurial 1.3** and later